LDO is not working as it supposed to (stability issue)
I have designed the following circuit for converting 11 V to 5 V (3 A), by using LT3083:

The schematic:

The PCB:

Fabricated PCB:

I have used two power resistors to make 1.7 Ω for drawing 3 A, the reason I used jumper to disconnect one the LDOs is that I wanted to see if two cheap will be thermally more efficient or there is not that difference for 3 A.
My issue:
When I apply 11V to the input, the circuit is just stable for 1 or 2 second and the output voltage goes down around 1V..
When I apply 6 V to the input the circuit is stable.
I measured the REST resistance when the circuit is getting hot it seems the REST is changed example form 50 kΩ to 43 kΩ, then I thought it is because of the temperature, the I soldered the RSET is way to not be affected by the PCB temperature:

But nothing changed, and the issue is there, the circuit is unstable. Please let me know if you have any idea that I can fix the issue.
Also there something on the page 11 of the datasheet call "Guard Ring Layout Example for DF Package", which I did not applied on my layout:


Is there a reason you have not got the recommended capacitor over the Rset resistor? And have you allowed for the impact of sharing Rset between the two devices? Both issues are likely to lead to stability issues.

So you do not actually have a stability (e.g. oscillation) but dissipation problem. With 11V input you are dissipating 18W split across the two regulators that are soldered on a miniature PCB with no heatsink to speak off.

Are you testing with an oscilloscope or just a multimeter? If you test with an oscilloscope is there an oscillation of the output before it drops to 1 V? Note on the 1st page of the datasheet: "Internal protection circuitry includes current limiting and
thermal limiting." --- one of these is almost surely your problem.

Also I don't see the 10 mOhm resistors from the reference design in your schematic --- these are important to allow current sharing.

Soooo, where did L1 come from in the layout? It's not in the schematic. Same applies to most of the resistors and capacitors. Don't give us conflicting schematic and layout. Also, both are hard to read due to low resolution. You should know better by now.

@colintd thank yo uvery much for the comment, in fact I have the cap C6, regarding sharing one Rset for botth chips, this is exactly what reference design asks to do.

@Raonoke thanks for your comment, yes, I agree, it could be dissipation problem.

@The Photon yes I do not have those 10mohm resistor, when I remove the jumper at least one of the LDOs should work, but it does not. the resistor is needed when there are two LDOs.

@marcelm thank you very much for your comment, that part of the circuit is another circuit (CUk convertor, which works fine), I just posted the part of the schematic that has problem.

As mentioned by Roanoke in comments, this is very likely a thermal dissipation issue. With 11 V input and 3 A load, your regulators dissipate 18 W between them.
But you haven't even connected the thermal pads of the chips to the output polygon areas except by one tiny bridge:

These pads are meant to be the main way to dissipate heat  to allow heat to be removed by convective cooling. Per the datasheet, "Internal protection circuitry includes current limiting and thermal limiting." so the kind of output drop you observed is exactly what you would expect in the event of overheating.
You should connect them with as low a thermal resistance as you can to a large outer-layer copper region. If you use a region on the bottom side of the board, use multiple vias to connect to it. Ideally remove solder mask from that region to allow maximum cooling from air flow over it.
Even then to dissipate 18 W you might find you need to increase the board area to achieve sufficient heat dissipation. Note the thermal dissipation tables on page 15 of the datasheet that show a 2500 mm2 copper region on both sides of the board is needed to achieve 16 C/W dissipation --- which would still give a 288 C temperature rise with 18 W dissipation, and lead to shut-down.
You may also have other issues, for example not including the 10 milliohm series resistors at the outputs to allow the two chips to share the load without one or the other being back-fed due to slight differences in their reference voltages.

Ask yourself how much copper you have on your PCB to deal with the 9 watts per package heat dissipation. If you have 16 °C/watt then, 9 watts is going to warm the junction to 144 °C and, in ambient of 25 °C that's a junction temperature of 169 °C but, the limit at which the device protects itself is 125 °C.

It's not going to work with one device dissipating 9 watts so, it isn't going to work with two devices at 18 watts. If you used the T0-220 package option you'll stand a better chance: -
Thermal Resistance (Junction-to-Case) = 3°C/W

However, you are still going to need some serious heatsinking compared to bare copper front and back. The big question is why you want to drop 6 volts across the device?
